# Cross-compiled Python can't find basic modules (math, operator, etc)

Tags: python, linux, embedded, cross-compiling

I can't seem to import any of the basic modules located in the "lib-dynload" directory.  They are all there, but I get the error: `"ImportError: No module named X"` when trying to import them.

I checked my `sys.path` and it includes the directory where all of these modules are located and my PYTHONHOME environment variable is set correctly.  I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the problem could be.  Some background info: This is cross-compiled from Python 2.6.6 source and installed onto an ARM embedded Linux board with Angstrom.

It did have python on there before, I had tried to bit-bake it into the image but it was missing a lot of stuff.  I ended up doing my best to clean the directory tree of anything to do with the previous python before loading on my cross compiled version.

An strace of a simple script that just attempts to import `math`:  http://pastebin.com/3XgJ3nPR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no checks in that trace for filenames like `math.so` or `mathmodule.so` which might indicate that shared-object modules are turned off entirely — that the version of Python you have compiled cannot load binary modules dynamically.

**More:** looking over the `config.out` from my most recent Python build, I see several lines where Python is investigating whether the platform will let it dynamically load binary modules that end in `.so`:

```
checking for dlopen... yes
checking DYNLOADFILE... dynload_shlib.o
checking MACHDEP_OBJS... MACHDEP_OBJS
```

What do these lines say on your cross-compile?

Comment: Would you happen to know what flag or variable to set in order for it to compile this way?  I can check the make/setup/configure results.

Comment: No — when I compile Python on Ubuntu for i386, it decides automatically that it is capable of loading shared objects. Maybe it checks for the `dlopen()` system call? Yes, it looks like it does — I will update my answer.

Comment: It checks for it in a couple places.  Relevant parts: http://pastebin.com/UQ2ZsteE .  The result is failure.  This must be the issue, thank you.  I'll look into how to solve this, any recommendations? FYI: I decided to switch kernels and corresponding tool chain recently, the previous tool chain cross compiled python without any issues.

Comment: No, no recommendations off the top of my head (just woke back up or I'd have responded faster) — it looks like the libc you are using knows *something* about `dlopen()`, because the error is more interesting than "unknown function"; which gives me hope that the platform can be induced to provide you with the function, if properly compiled and configured. But clearly `dlopen()` is not fully available the way it's currently set up.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run across a similar issue building Python 2.7.13, and I believe it is [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue28444) which is being fixed for Python 3 but not ported back to 2. The build process (setup.py) generates a list of modules to build, and then subtracts the list of built-in modules (`sys.builtin_module_names`); however, setup.py is run (from the Makefile) using `python2.7` which in my case picked up the system (Ubuntu) binary rather than the one built, so it subtracts off modules that are built-in for the system python (including operator and collections) but not for the one being built, so they are neither built-in nor built as external modules.

I was able to use a suggestion from the bug and prepend the built python, in the source directory, to the path (and add a symlink from python2.7 -> python). This worked because I was building an x86 python on a multi-arch x64 machine; if you are building for another system like ARM you may need to apply the patch from the bug to get the list of built-in modules from earlier in the build process rather than the host python.